# Deploying Branch Plan in Bamboo - How to define arbitrary release version for automatic deployments

Tags: deployment, versioning, bamboo

We are using Bamboo 5.2 for continuous integration.

Source plan has several additional branches. Each branch is triggered by commits in git repo.

Deployment project is configured with separate environment for each branch, deployment happens automatically on successful build of source plan.

When **default** branch is deployed automatically - new release is created correctly with naming schema defined in "Release versioning" (we use source plan variables to create release version).

The problem appears when any other branch is deployed automatically - we get new release with default version. As bamboo states: "Releases from branches will default to using the branch name suffixed with the build number of the build result."

Is there any possibility to override this approach? 
Target is to set release version from plan's variables (no matter default plan variables or branch plan variables), reason is that we have single plan with several stable branches configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bamboo 6.1.0 Atlassian has solved the problem!
Please see https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-14422.
Since now on naming for releases created on non-default branches follow defined naming rules.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to select which branch to use. Under Triggers:

- Branch to trigger this deployment
- Use the main plan branch

Comment: Choice of branch will perfectly deploy proper build to the given environment BUT ... this doesn't help with Release naming. Only releases linked with master branch can have arbitrary logic of naming. Releases linked with branches have fixed naming rule :(

Comment: true i believe. If you have bamboo server you might be able to write a script to add your own naming convention to those branches though.